# Calculating the average of multiple rows in single file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, average

I have a CSV file that I want to minimize.

The file looks like so:

```
Ticker  |    Date     |   Marketcap 
  A     |  2002-03-14 |    600000
  A     |  2002-03-14 |    520000
  A     |  2004-03-16 |    400000
  A     |  2004-03-16 |    680000
  A     |  2008-07-14 |    500000
  A     |  2010-03-14 |    300000
  AB    |  2010-02-14 |    1200000
  AB    |  2010-02-14 |    930000
  AB    |  2010-02-14 |    1600000
  AB    |  2012-05-02 |    1600000
  AB    |  2012-05-02 |    1300000
```

As you can see len(A) /= len(AB) and the marketcaps for repeated dates are not the same for every entry of the same ticker.

What I need to do is calculate the **averages** of each **ticker** with the same **date** and then parse these averages into a new CSV that looks like this type of **output**:

```
Ticker  |    Date     |   Avg Marketcap 
  A     |  2002-03-14 |    560000
  A     |  2004-03-16 |    540000
  A     |  2008-07-14 |    500000
  A     |  2010-03-14 |    300000
  AB    |  2010-02-14 |    124333
  AB    |  2012-05-02 |    1450000
```

I've tried searching sample codes to begin but all I can find is concatenating two files together or multiple dataframes; nothing within the same set.

My code simply parses my file and currently looks like:

```
#Parse values from 2003 and above
df = pd.read_csv(data_market)
df = df[(df['Date'] > '2003-01-01')]
df = df[['Ticker','Date','Marketcap']]

#Dropping duplicate values
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate the averages of each _year_ and each ticker? Or each _date_ and ticker?

Comment: Of each of the same **date** with the same **ticker** as I've given above as what I'm looking to **output**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### one line exact solution

```
df.groupby(['Ticker', 'Date'], as_index=False).mean()

#Output
  Ticker        Date     Marketcap
0      A  2002-03-14  5.600000e+05
1      A  2004-03-16  5.400000e+05
2      A  2008-03-14  5.000000e+05
3      A  2010-03-14  3.000000e+05
4     AB  2010-02-14  1.243333e+06
5     AB  2012-05-02  1.450000e+06
```

Answer (score 3):

First make sure your `Date` column is `datetime`

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Then just group by Ticker and year, and take [`mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)

```
df.groupby(["Ticker", df.Date.dt.year]).mean().round().reset_index()


Ticker  Date    Marketcap
0   A   2002    560000.0
1   A   2004    540000.0
2   A   2008    500000.0
3   A   2010    300000.0
4   AB  2010    1243333.0
5   AB  2012    1450000.0
```

Comment: I can't figure out why this method isn't working for me outside of a thought that it may have something to do with the date.

I don't actually want to change the date from an actual date to a year total but simply take the averages of the same exact dates and keep it in tact.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There was no error. It parsed through just fine and when inspecting the table it was as if I hadn't even passed the line into the code; no averaging done and kept the same values.

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect my current code without addition of averages.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a small trick here

```
df.groupby([df.Ticker,df.Date.str[:4]]).Marketcap.mean()
Out[31]: 
Ticker  Date
A       2002    5.600000e+05
        2004    5.400000e+05
        2008    5.000000e+05
        2010    3.000000e+05
AB      2010    1.243333e+06
        2012    1.450000e+06
Name: Marketcap, dtype: float64
```

To match what you expected , using `agg`

```
df.groupby([df.Ticker,df.Date.str[:4]]).agg({'Marketcap':'mean','Date':'first'}).reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
Out[46]: 
           Marketcap        Date
Ticker                          
A       5.600000e+05  2002-03-14
A       5.400000e+05  2004-03-16
A       5.000000e+05  2008-03-14
A       3.000000e+05  2010-03-14
AB      1.243333e+06  2010-02-14
AB      1.450000e+06  2012-05-02
```